# how to freeze some layer after restore only part of a pretrained model in tensorflow？

Tags: tensorflow

I have successfully restored part of a pretrained model using those code:

```
network = importlib.import_module(args.model_def)
exclude = ['InceptionResnetV1/Bottleneck/BatchNorm/beta']
include = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(include=include, exclude=exclude)
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
saver.restore(sess, pretrained_model_dir)
```

Then I want to only freeze these restored layer,what should I do?

As I had the list of these tensor, I think there are two method（but don't know how to code ）:

```
（1）set those tensor in the 'variables_to_restore' list to constant
（2）set those tensor in the 'variables_to_restore' list to 'untrainable'
```